# How to get the batch size inside lambda layer

Tags: keras

I'm trying to implement a layer (via lambda layer) which is doing the following numpy procedure:

```
def func(x, n):
    return np.concatenate((x[:, :n], np.tile(x[:, n:].mean(axis = 0), (x.shape[0], 1))), axis = 1)
```

I'm stuck because I don't know how to get the size of the first dimension of x (which is the batch size). The backend function `int_shape(x)` returns `(None, ...)`.

So, if I know the batch_size, the corresponding Keras procedure would be:

```
def func(x, n):
    return K.concatenate([x[:, :n], K.tile(K.mean(x[:, n:], axis=0), [batch_size, 1])], axis = 1)
```

Comment: You must have set `batch_size` somewhere in your code, just use that variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: In my setup every batch has its own size.

Comment: I tried it, but K.int_shape(x)[0] = None. I suspect that int_shape returns the size not for the vary batch, but the input shape of the layer. And this is (None, n1, n2, ...) because the first dimension is batch size and it can be any value.

Comment: Do you know that you could provide a function instead of value to a `output_shape`? This function takes as an argument `input_shape`. You could define your own be e.g. `lambda x: (x[0], 1)`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I define the output_shape. However, I have the problem not with the defining output_shape, but with the implementation of the target tensor transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @pitfall says, the second argument of `K.tile` should be a tensor.
And according to [the doc of keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/), `K.shape` returns a tensor and `K.int_shape` returns a tuple of int or None entries. So the correct way is to use `K.shape`. Following is the MWE:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

batch_size = 8
op_len = ip_len = 10

def func(X):
    return K.tile(K.mean(X, axis=0, keepdims=True), (K.shape(X)[0], 1))

ip = Input((ip_len,))
lbd = Lambda(lambda x:func(x))(ip)

model = Model(ip, lbd)
model.summary()

model.compile('adam', loss='mse')

X = np.random.randn(batch_size*100, ip_len)
Y = np.random.randn(batch_size*100, op_len)
#no parameters to train!
#model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=batch_size)

#prediction
np_result = np.tile(np.mean(X[:batch_size], axis=0, keepdims=True), 
                    (batch_size,1))
pred_result = model.predict(X[:batch_size])
print(np.allclose(np_result, pred_result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `K.int_shape`, but something like [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape), which will give you a dynamic shape.

---

### New updates

Here is a solution without using `tile`

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *

# define the lambda layer
n = 5
MyConcat = Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate([x[:,:n], 
                                           K.ones_like(x[:,n:]) * K.mean(x[:,n:], axis=0)],
                                          axis=1))

# make a dummy testing model
x = Input(shape=(10,))
y = MyConcat(x)
mm = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

# test code
a = np.arange(40).reshape([-1,10])
print(a)
```

> [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
>    [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
>    [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
>    [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]]

```
b = mm.predict(a)
print(b)
```

> [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]
>    [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]
>    [20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]
>    [30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]]

---

The last thing that wants to mention is --- in `keras` you are not allowed to change the `batch-size` within a layer, namely the output and input `batch size` of a layer **MUST** be the same.

Comment: This usually returns a `None` value which is useless for doing anything logical with the batch size.

Comment: If you have not tried what I said, please don't down-vote my solution. To be more precise, I update my answer with reproducible code.

Comment: Just notice that @keineahnung2345 has already provided the right solution. So I update my solution without using `tile`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a functor and give it the batch size at the initialization.

```
class SuperLoss:
    def __init__(self,batch_size):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def __call__(self,y_true,y_pred):
        self.batch_size ....
```

Comment: In my setup every batch has its own size. I train a model using model.fit_generator, so I have a generator which generates batches (and in my problem different batch sizes naturally arise). So, I need to pass new batch size to a functor every time. Is there a way to do this?