# Flatten entire batch in Tensorflow Keras functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to faltten an entire batch in my network to further process data.

Here is an example of a layer I would like to flatten completely (including batch dimension)

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x) # has shape [None, 128]
x = Flatten(shape=(-1)) # Example function, should have shape [batch_size x 128]
# process x
x = Unflatten(shape=[None, 128]) # Example function, has again shape [None, 128]
# ...
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668542/flatten-batch-in-tensorflow) post, which seems not to cover Tensorflow 2.x. How can I flatten an entire batch in TF 2.x?

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. From the question it sounds like you have an input with shape [batch_size, features] and you want it to have a shape of [0, features]. Well what is happening to the rest of the input?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow2 offers a Reshape layer. (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape).

Comment: I know. But the documentation states the following: `Target shape. Tuple of integers, does not include the samples dimension (batch size).`. So it does not fully flatten since the batch dimension is not considered.

Comment: Ah okay. A question: Why do you not merge the data before training? Normally the batches should be i.i.d. and shouldn't correlate at all. Maybe this will help here by using a lambda layer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841096/how-to-get-the-batch-size-inside-lambda-layer